# I'm having difficulty understanding this code

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int* c = &a;
int* d = &b;
c = d;
*d = 3;
cout << a << " " << b;
```

Quite simply I don't get how *d = 3 makes b = 3. I thought d needs to equal the address of b to do so?

Comment: d does equal the address of b.

Comment: What do you think the `int* d = &b;` line does? ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I thought it points to the address of b so if I outputted *d it would give me the address of b.

Comment: Your code *says* d = &b.

Comment: Sorry for the bad tags n title, but, my confusion got the best of me.  Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irrelevant differences aside, this

```
int* d = &b;
```

is just a shorter form of this

```
int* d;
d = &b;
```

After that `d` contains address of `b`. I.e. `d` is the address of `b`. `d` does not "point to the address" of `b`, it *is* the address of `b`.

Now `*d` is equivalent to `b`. Everything you do to `*d` will happen to `b`.